# Is it possible to convert JSON to XML and XML to JSON without serializing/deserializing to a Specific Object

Tags: xml, json, delphi, serialization

Parse JSON and create XML formatted file that still represents the data. (SuperXMLParser adds all the #children/#name tags). 
Parse XML and create a JSON formatted file. (arrays/objects/...)

Use a generic object but create correct JSON/XML data from the generic object.
Or do I have to use a specific object in order to get the correctly formatted output formats?

Comment: It's possible.  I've seen code for it, but that was at a previous job and I no longer have it available.

Comment: You could use XSLT to create JSON from XML.

Comment: What about from Delphi?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982687/how-do-i-display-xml-using-an-xslt-document-in-a-delphi-app and https://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/

Comment: Yeah Warren sort of the same issue. I thought I had all the issues worked out but when I got to testing everything then (numbers/integers/boolean/...) were no longer correct/same. So the scope of my task has grown larger now. (attributes and so on)

Answer (score 1):

For TMongoWire I created a JSON parser that fills a IBSONDocument object, which is basically a key-value-collection based on OleVariant's:

https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire/blob/master/bsonUtils.pas

That answers the part of the question about converting without deserialization. To generate the XML you could copy `JsonToBson` but generate XML instead.