# What can be done when XSLT transformation using msxml doesn't match root node ('/')?

Tags: xml, delphi, xslt, msxml

I'm running an XSLT 1.0 transformation using Delphi/MSXML. The XSLT goes like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:lh="http://localhost" 
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My Book Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="lh:library/lh:book">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@author"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the XML `books.xml` is define as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library xmlns="http://localhost">
    <book author="Michael Howard">Writing Secure Code</book>
    <book author="Michael Kay">XSLT Reference</book>
</library>
```

When I run this [XSLT transformation using Delphi/MSXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001305/182048), it doesn't output anything.

Saxon, for reference, yields the following result (1.0/2.0 warning message not included):

```
<html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:lh="http://localhost">
   <body>
      <h2>My Book Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Title</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Michael Howard</td>
            <td>Writing Secure Code</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Michael Kay</td>
            <td>XSLT Reference</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

What can I do about the XML (the XSLT is not really for me to change) to give the same output as in Saxon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run the transformation with the document nodes; change in the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001305/960757) this line:

```
XML.DocumentElement.TransformNode(XSL.DocumentElement, Result)
```

to:

```
XML.Node.TransformNode(XSL.Node, Result)
```

If you explictly call the `transformNode` on the `documentElement` node then it does not surprise me that the `match="/"` does not get applied.

Comment: Thanks Martin! That's awesome - I truely appreciate it! :) One a side note: the Delphi documentation for the implementing class [TXMLDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument_Properties) says 'DocumentElement provides access to the root node of the XML document' while 'Node provides access to the document node for the XML document', which I find slightly confusing.